# How do you use overflow hidden with unordered list?

Tags: html, overflow, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

### -

### -

What am I missing here? I want to keep my unordered list on one single line and be overflow:hidden... I know that I could also re-write the html in a way that i could absolute position the arrows on a high z-index, and the li's on a lower z-index, but i DONT want to do that. I want the ul to flow naturally, but I'm having an issue with this. Which is the preferred method?

This is what I've got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/pTaTc/

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 8</a></li>
<li class="arrow-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="left-arrow"><</a>
    <a href="#" class="right-arrow">></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
    * { font-family: arial; font-size: 1em; }

    ul { position: relative; background: black; padding: 1em; }
    li { display: inline; }
    a { color: white; text-decoration: none; padding: 1em 2em; display: inline-block; }
    .arrow-wrapper { background: black; }
    .arrow-wrapper a { color: #54bdff; font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; line-height:.75; }
    .left-arrow { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
    .right-arrow { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; }




    /* Black gradient for arrows */
    .left-arrow {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    .right-arrow {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+         */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */    
    }
```

As always, your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `ul`.

For more on [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: wow. i feel like an idiot.. because im pretty sure i tried that on the wrong element!,, but it works perfectly. Thankyou.

Comment: @mrrioku Do you mind accepting the answer?  I just got enough reputation to comment.

Comment: I tried to accept it but it told me to wait 3 minutes.. haha... i actually pinpointed the problem on my project,,, it was inheriting a float:left on the li and that is what the underlying issue was.